# ExtJS Missing url for ServerProxy in a tagfield

Tags: url, extjs, proxy-server

I'm currently creating a Ext JS component that will be used to translate in different languages some words.

But I'm facing a problem, when I'm editing the list of words there is an uncaught error.

> Uncaught Error: You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.

The problem is that I don't use a server proxy and I really don't know where this error comes from.

fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lbc

As someone an idea ?

Baptiste C.

Answer (score 1):

I forked you fiddle and added `proxy` type of `memory` in your `translationStore`.
 Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lbo)

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory'
}
```